# Adobe Flash Inserting Button on movie?

Tags: flash, adobe, actionscript-2, flash-cs5, movieclip

I have one movie. is there any way to import it on Adobe Flash and insert some button on fifth minutes of this movie? I means after four minutes of playing this movie, my buttons appear and by selecting *continue* button movie playing is continued and by clicking on *exit*, my movie will be closed? is there any way for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I started to have a go at answering this but I ran into some issues see: http://rupert.id.au/flash/

I was thinking if you could import your video into the timeline you could then place a stop action stop(); action at the 4 minute mark and add a button that would

```
on (release) {
play();
}
```

The problem is that your video will produce a huge SWF file and the audio will get out of sync if you use this approach.

I then though you might be able to link to a FLV video online eg: 
http://rupert.id.au/flash/video/countdown-582-360.flv and place a button on the time line at the point you want to stop playing but I have not been able to get this to work properly.  As the linked video keeps playing past the Action Script.